# Import Url path to postgreSQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, fastapi

I am using FastAPI
I have a POST method with a url like this: `'/{id}/report'`
I want to have the id parameter in my database, but I don't want to add it in the request body. I want to extract it from url and add it to my PostgreSQL database.
how can I do this?

Comment: Please see  [https://progressivecoder.com/how-to-use-fastapi-query-parameters/]

Comment: You want to have `id` parameter but don't want in body. then that would be GET request.

Comment: @AbhishekJadav I want to enter it as url and post it to my database without setting it in body again, if my URL was 12/report I want to have this 12 in my database and not giving it in body again

Comment: @Saha POST request are mainly used to create or update resource. In your case `12/report` means that resource with **id = 12** already exists in database and i think it's not good idea to update as the id column of the table will be **primary key**. 

Although which tech stack(Backend and Frontend) you are using?

Comment: First; select a better name than just ´id`, since `id` is also an internal Python function. You can extract any route parameter by using `report_id: str = Path(...)` in your view signature. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/ How you then insert or manipulate this in Postgres will depend on how you're connecting to and using the database.